# Literature for $G$-graded rings

Tags: abstract-algebra, reference-request, book-recommendation, graded-algebras

I am searching for a book which contains very basic statements (with proofs) of $G-$ (respectively $\mathbb{Z}-$) graded rings and ideals. (For example that $R/I$ is a $G$-graded ring if $I$ is a graded ideal.) I was already looking in Lang's Algebra but was not able to find anything useful, except a short passage in section X.5.

Comment: https://math.unl.edu/~tmarley1/905notes.pdf

Answer (score 1):

Your could take a look at "Methods of Graded Rings" by Nastacescu and van Oystaeyen, or "Graded Rings and Graded Grothendieck Groups" by Hazrat. There are many other references, either dedicated to the subject, or just giving a reasonable treatment.